# Query a table while excluding values referenced in other tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a database filled with transactions from various bank accounts. Each transactions comes with a `user_id`, `bank_id`, `account_id` and a `transaction_id`. I'd like to exclude transactions when querying, if the user chooses to ignore a bank, account or an individual transaction.

In other words, if a user:

- ignores a bank, all transactions with that `bank_id` are skipped,
- ignores an account, all transactions with that `account_id` are skipped,
- ignores an individual transaction, the transaction with that `transaction_id` is skipped.

My current database looks like this:

```
-- Simplified for brevity.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions
(
    user_id        TEXT NOT NULL,
    transaction_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    account_id     TEXT NOT NULL,
    bank_id        TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, transaction_id)
);

-- Exclusion tables for banks and accounts are similar.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS excluded_transactions
(
    id             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    user_id        TEXT NOT NULL,
    transaction_id TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS exc_trn_idx ON excluded_transactions (user_id, transaction_id);
```

Whenever a user `abc` excludes a bank, account or a transaction, it is added to the appropriate exclusion table. The query then looks like this:

```
WITH b AS (
  SELECT bank_id FROM excluded_banks WHERE user_id = 'abc'
), a AS (
  SELECT account_id FROM excluded_accounts WHERE user_id = 'abc'
), t AS (
  SELECT transaction_id FROM excluded_transactions WHERE user_id = 'abc'
)
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE user_id = 'abc'
AND bank_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM b) 
AND account_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM a)
AND transaction_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM t)
```

This gives an *OK* performance on a test set of ~1M transactions (~100ms planning time, ~1s execution time, on average). However, I'm worried it will degrade significantly as the database grows.

**My question is**: how can I improve the tables/queries to efficiently retrieve transactions with the constraints mentioned above? Slower writes are acceptable if they make the reads faster. Also, if the general approach I took is suboptimal, please let me know and/or suggest an improved one.

Comment: How many exclusions would you expect. If the exclusion tables grow large then performance is going to suffer, but broadly the query you have looks efficient (to me, so doesn't exactly mean all that much)

Comment: In addition to using NOT EXISTS rather than NOT IN, why have "excluded_transactions" at all?  It doesn't look like one user can exclude a different user's transactions, just have a flag directly on "transactions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM transactions t
WHERE t.user_id = 'abc' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM excluded_banks eb
                  WHERE eb.bank_id = t.bank_id AND
                        eb.user_id = t.user_id
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM excluded_accounts ea
                  WHERE ea.account_id = t.account_id AND
                        ea.user_id = t.user_id
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM excluded_transaction et
                  WHERE et.transaction_id = t.transaction_id AND
                        et.user_id = t.user_id
                 );
```

Then be sure you have the following indexes:

- `excluded_banks(user_id, bank_id)`
- `excluded_accounts(user_id, account_id)`
- `excluded_transaction(user_id, transaction_id)`